# How to avoid lag with Unity MovePlayerOnYAxis in iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

My script works on Android very well and doesn't slow down, but when I try to use it on IoS sometimes it goes very good, and sometimes it lags and move player by 1 inch or less, and I don't know how to fix it. FPS doesn't go down, it stays stable at 60fps.

```
void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
    {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
            newPosition.y += Mathf.Clamp(touch.deltaPosition.y * speed, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = newPosition;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code taken out of context is too little information to allow an actual answer, therefore here my opinion that will help you to investigate this  better.

In my opinion the lag is hardly related to the OS handling touches, it's most likely an issue related to other operations you are performing at each frame. Android and iOS manage threads, rendering and memory very differently, so the simple fact that you mention 60FPS makes me think that you are hitting some sort of race condition: the optimal frame rate on mobile is 30, so I'd suggest to start the investigation by first limiting the frame rate putting the following in one of your scripts:

```
    void Awake() {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
    }
```

That will leave enough compute power to the engine and the OS to perform other tasks, hence it's a good starting point in your investigation.

Comment: @Giuseppe_De_Francesco I`ve used targetframerate=60 , i have alot of moving objects so if i use 30fps it lags but if 60fps player sometimes glitches and moves slow , but everything is fine

Comment: @PeterisUlmanis that explains it then, you are facing a resource management racing condition. Please also note that 60FPS will kill the device battery rather quick... not a good practice. There are a lot of techniques to have a lot happening on the screen while running at even less than 30FPS to save battery life: I'd suggest to dig some scene optimization theory to solve your problem correctly.